# Angular: Differentiate between a parameter and child route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router, angular2-resolve

I have a situation where, I want a resolver if the child route is a param, and not if it's a path segment. Below is my code.

```
{
    path: 'agreement',
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: AgreementComponent,
        resolve: { agreementDetails: AgreementDetailsResolveService }
      },
      {
        path: 'create',
        component: AgreementComponent
      }
    ]
  }
```

When I hit the path `agreement/create`, it's throwing error, as `create` is considered as the value of the param `id` and it's invalid.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rearrange your route definition:

```
{
    path: 'agreement',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'create',
        component: AgreementComponent
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: AgreementComponent,
        resolve: { agreementDetails: AgreementDetailsResolveService }
      }
    ]
  }
```